# Swift Package Manager Creating Multiple Target Schemes in Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

I'm new to SPM (Swift Package Manager), when I try to install firebase swift package, I can see that there are multiple targets created.

I goto **Manage scheme** and **uncheck** the **show** that is removed the targets temporarily after I delete derived data again the package refreshed and all the targets are start to show in the list.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Update to Firebase 8.1.0 to get some reduction of the extra schemes.

See discussions at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/8167 and https://forums.swift.org/t/swiftpm-and-library-unit-testing/26255/21 to track additional progress.